Soft question: Probability problems book recommendation
I'm studying Probability Theory this semester and am looking for books with quality problems.
Last semester, I had a Calculus course and my lecturer took exercises from Problems in Mathematical Analysis by Demidovich, which was written by russian mathematicians. That book has many challenging problems.
Can somebody recommend some Probability books like that?
I know this question has been asked before but I am really having trouble choosing books with such a large number of exercises.

I have always viewed Durrett's book as one which is great for self study as well as one which has lots of good problems.

Thanks for the respone, i'll check it.
